# Unable to parse json returned by the server, in file ext-all.js

Tags: javascript, php, json, extjs

I'm running some programming example's and the server send me this message: [WARN]Unable to parse json returnde by the server.

I'm using xampp stack in ubuntu 14.04, the warning points to the file ext-all.js, the page can't connect with the database. please help!!

the code is in the ext-all.js file! i didn't touch the file!

Comment: Can you provide the json your getting back?  Try parsing the json through a online json parses like this one: http://json.parser.online.fr/ to make sure the json is valid.

Comment: what is the response that you are getting from server?I think,the problem is there,and can you provide us the code for handling the response?so that we can help you.

Comment: i can't provide you an image of the error, the server just send me that message: [WARN] Unable to parse JSON returned by the server, and points me to the library of extjs file ext-all.js, i parse the really large json file in the page that loanburger recommend and threw me an syntax error:  unexpected token v